# Adding Icons to a folder - Changes folder to read-only - Removing read-only removes icon

Tags: windows-10, icons

A gif speaks a thousand words.

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
```

### See the problem.

[image: gif]

1. Add the icon file.
2. Then refresh to show the icon.
3. Run cmd as admin
4. cd to the folder in question.
5. Run `attrib -r "%cd%"`
6. Run `attrib -r "%cd%\*.*"`
7. The removes the read-only props and also the icon file as well.

Are there any ways around this problem of the folder becoming read-only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no workaround. Windows will process the [desktop.ini](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini) file only if the corresponding folder is marked read-only.

However, marking a folder read-only doesn't prevent you from creating/editing files in that folder. 'Read-only' has no meaning for folders.

Comment: Thanks for that. Marked as the solution.